# How to remove the interuption of a vertical line in a table

Tags: tables, vertical

I have seen similar questions here. However, all of the code in the other started with  `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}` which I want to avoid. How do I get rid of the space between the vertical line?[image]

```
 \documentclass[letter,11pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{subfig,rotating,longtable,lscape,geometry,layouts}
    \usepackage{makecell}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!] 
    \small
    \hspace*{-0.3cm}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{1.7cm}
      @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      l
      *{3}{
        S[table-format=4.0]
        S[table-format=4.0]
        S[table-format=4.0]
      }
      @{}
    }
    \par\noindent\rule[-2mm]{16.5cm}{0.3mm} \\

    \multicolumn{2}{c|} {} & {\makecell{text}} & {\makecell{text}} & {text} & {text} \\
    \par\noindent\rule[0mm]{16.5cm}{0.2mm}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{c|} {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}  & {text}  \\ 
        \vspace{-0.5cm}
    \par\noindent\rule[1mm]{16.5cm}{0.3mm}
    \end{tabular*} 
    \vspace{-0.2cm}
    \caption{text} 
    \label{idealized}  
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Please use `\hline` instead of `\par\noindent\rule[0mm]{16.5cm}{0.2mm}\\ `

Comment: Why do you load `booktabs` and not use it?

Comment: Nowadays you really should not be using vertical lines in data tables anyway. Studies show that the vertical lines makes it harder to read each row. The rules from booktabs are explicitly designed with this in mind.

Comment: Why you use `S` column types and than you have text in columns?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you like to have something like this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l *{4}{C} }
    \toprule
        & text  &   text    &   text    &   text    \\
    \midrule
text    & text  &   text    &   text    &   text    \\
text    & text  &   text    &   text    &   text    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{text}
\label{idealized}
    \end{table}
\end{document}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead of all the manual spaces and lines:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfig,rotating,longtable,lscape,geometry,layouts}
\usepackage{makecell}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!] 
\small
%\hspace*{-0.3cm}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    p{1.7cm}|
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  *{4}{
    S[table-format=4.0]
  }
  @{}
}
\hline
 & {\makecell{text}} & {\makecell{text}} & {text} & {text} \\
 \hline
  {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}  & {text}  \\ 
  \hline 
\end{tabular*} 
%\vspace{-0.2cm}
\caption{text} 
\label{idealized}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Why you have 11 columns, if your table only have 5?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, your question is not clear ... For example, what you like to achieve with

```
  *{3}{
        S[table-format=4.0]
        S[table-format=4.0]
        S[table-format=4.0]
      }
```

it is the same as

```
*{0}{S[table-format=4.0]}
```

Than why you use `S` columns if your table body don't contain numbers.

For horizontal rules in table are defined my special lines, from standard `\hline` and `cline` to `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `bottomrule` defined in `booktabs` package and many others. Why you use `\rule` which is not intended for such an use?

See, if the following guessing what you after is correct:

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,makecell,multirow}
\setcellgapes{3pt}  % for more vrtical space around cells contents
                    % defined in the 'makecell' package
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \makegapedcells % for more vrtical space around cells contents
                    % defined in the 'makecell' package
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{ p{1.7cm}| @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                              l 
                         *{9}{S[table-format=4.0]}
                            }
    \Xhline{1pt}    % defined in the 'makecell' package
        & some text
        &   {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}  
        &   {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}
        &   {text}  &   {text}  &   {text}  \\
    \hline
text    & some text
        &   1234    &   1234    &   1234    
        &   1234    &   1234    &   1234
        &   1234    &   1234    &   1234    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Caption text}
\label{idealized}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]